# Create Addons for GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

Is there a complete guide - example describing how to create an add-on/plugin for the GRASS GIS?

I would like to extend the GUI with extra menus and toolbars creating extra functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here:

- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2014-September/070622.html
- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2014-September/070624.html

Essentially, for GUI customization, see

http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/wxGUIDevelopment/Toolboxes